# VMWare on Linux - Could not open /dev/vmmon

Tags: vmware

## How to fix VMWare Could not open /dev/vmmon

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [VMWare article 2146460](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146460)

> On Linux host with secure mode enabled, it is not allowed to load any unsigned drivers. Due to this, VMware drivers, such as vmmon and vmnet, are not able to be loaded which prevents virtual machine to power on.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMWare"
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
sudo shutdown -r now
```

---

*During the very next startup, you may need to enter MOK Management during boot, and select "ENROLL MOK" to import the key, and reboot once more.*

Comment: During the next startup, you still need to tap "Enter" to enter MOK management, and then select "ENROLL MOK" to import the keys.

Comment: Is it possible this messes with the BIOS, and block other disks from booting UEFI drives?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 20.04 solution that worked for me:

```sh
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMWare"
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)
sudo su
mokutil --import MOK.der
input password:
input password again:
exit
sudo shutdown -r now
```

At startup "ENROLL MOK" and "Restart" again.

Comment: It did it for me on ubuntu 20.04. You may need to interrupt manually the boot to enter the BIOS menu and select the "Mok" entry.

Comment: How can this work if `modinfo -n vmmon` returns an error ? These modules appears to be gone from Ubuntu 22.xx

Answer (score 1):

This may work with Ubuntu but with RHEL 7.8/8 I use the following commands (as root):

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout VMWare.priv -outform DEF -out VMWare.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"

/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./VMWare.priv ./VMWare.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)
/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./VMWare.priv ./VMWare.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)

mokutil --import VMWare.der
reboot
```

I get `Cant't find private key` when I sign vmnet/vmmon however, other articles on the internet have indicated that this is OK.

The mok is imported and then I try to run VMWare and I get `Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure that the kernel module 'vmmon' is loaded.`. If I make sure RHEL 7.8 is fully up to date the computer does not get the UEFI splash screen.

This is my post on the Unix/Linux stack exchange channel
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605037/unable-to-run-vmware-on-rhel-8-after-signing-vmmon-and-vmnet